# Shift + Enter no longer adds a new line in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, newline, hotkeys

Something I noticed recently. `Shift+Enter` does nothing (use to enter a new line) on VSCode on Windows.

Anyone know how to fix this? Other window's vs-code users is it happening to you too?

```
Version: 1.85.2 (user setup)
Commit: 8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681
Date: 2024-01-18T06:40:10.514Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 26354273
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
```

Comment: If you are trying to add a newline below the current line, the keybinding is `Ctrl+Enter`.  I don't think that has changed in a long time.  Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: for what language mode? there are several keybindings that override the editor shift+enter, such as Python's "run selected line in terminal", and in jupyter notebooks or interactive Python files.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Thanks @starball yeah one of the extensions is causing Shift+Enter to not add a newline.

I'm not sure how to mark this question as answered. If you copy and paste your comment as an answer I will mark it as such. Thank you!

Comment: which extension? what is its extension ID / marketplace page URL?